# How to run Groovy scripts from Emacs?

Tags: emacs, groovy

I found the [Emacs-Groovy-mode plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Emacs+Groovy+Mode), but it's not working properly

**Groovy script**

```
println "Hello, emacs"
```

**Configuration**

```lisp
(require 'inf-groovy)

;;; use groovy-mode when file ends in .groovy or has #!/bin/groovy at start
(autoload 'groovy-mode "groovy-mode" "Major mode for editing Groovy code." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.groovy$" . groovy-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("groovy" . groovy-mode))

;;; make Groovy mode electric by default.
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (require 'groovy-electric)
             (groovy-electric-mode)))
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.refjava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.setColor() is applicable for argument types:
```

Comment: The stacktrace you get, where does it come from? When you type your script in the inf-groovy interpreter?